# unity / vrtk does not contain a defination errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, vrtk

I was using Unity and Oculus together. I recently uninstalled both packages. And now I want to reload them. I import oculus first and then VRTK.
However, after importing vrtk I get the following errors:

```
Assets\VRTK\Source\SDK\Oculus\SDK_OculusController.cs(107,61): error CS0117: 'OVRInput.Controller' does not contain a definition for 'Touchpad';

Assets\VRTK\Source\SDK\Oculus\SDK_OculusController.cs(112,62): error CS0117: 'OVRInput.Controller' does not contain a definition for 'LTrackedRemote'

Assets\VRTK\Source\SDK\Oculus\SDK_OculusController.cs(112,99): error CS0117: 'OVRInput.Controller' does not contain a definition for 'RTrackedRemote'

Assets\VRTK\Source\SDK\Oculus\SDK_OculusHeadset.cs(78,46): error CS0117: 'OVRPlugin.SystemHeadset' does not contain a definition for 'GearVR_R320'

...
```

Could I be getting this error because I previously deleted files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that Oculus has reoved support to GearVR in their latest updates. If you are not using GearVR you can comment the problematic code at VRTK files in your unity project.